# Strange encoding for HTML greater than sign

Tags: php, html, encoding

So if you go [here](http://littlenomads.azurewebsites.net/destinations/) and inspect with F12 Tools the source for the breadcrumbs "Home > Destinations" there is a ">" between a `<b>` element.

This is not a key typed greater than sign in the HTML source ">". It is a "smaller" greater than sign and I can't figure out the encoding.

If I copy and paste the HTML `<b>›</b>` into notepad and upload, I get an encoding character issue [here](http://d42.e13.myftpupload.com/)

Any ideas what is the hex for this character, I have tried:

```
&#65125;
&#xfe65;
&gt; //I knew that wouldn't work but I tried it anyways
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's `&rsaquo;`, "Single right-pointing angle quotation mark".

Comment: Perfect, that is the answer! Cannot accept for 9 minutes, will accept answer then, thanks johnwait!